# (Python) Is it possible to use a list as an argument in this way?

Tags: python, list

I'd like to pass a list as an argument, and have Python recognize the first list item that fits the criteria I'm looking for. For instance, instead of having this:

```
sentence = "This is a sentence."

words = sentence.split()

for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i].startswith("a") or words[i].startswith("e") or words[i].startswith("i") or words[i].startswith("o") or words[i].startswith("u") or words[i].startswith("y"):
        words[i] += "yay"
```

I'd have something like this:

```
sentence = "This is a sentence."

words = sentence.split()

vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"]

for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i].startswith(vowels):
        words[i] += "yay"
```

Thank you

Comment: `if any(words[i].startswith(vowel) for vowel in vowels)`

Comment: If a function doesn't accept a list as argument it won't work. "startswith" doesn't accept a list.

Comment: Make `vowels` a tuple instead of a list, and `startswith()` will accept it.  (This is a specific feature of the `startswith` method, not anything general.)

Comment: @jasonharper TIL.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `word[0] in vowels` rather than trying to use `str.startswith`:

```
>>> words = "This is a sentence.".split()
>>> vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"]
>>> [w + "yay" if w[0] in vowels else w for w in words]
['This', 'isyay', 'ayay', 'sentence.']
```

but you could use `startswith` by iterating over `vowels` in a call to `any`:

```
>>> [w + "yay" if any(w.startswith(v) for v in vowels) else w for w in words]
['This', 'isyay', 'ayay', 'sentence.']
```